# DomPDF image is blurry (sometimes)

Tags: php, dompdf

I'm using DomPDF to generate a Invoice PDF that needs a QR-code on the PDF.
I'm getting the QR-code from a Google bucket where they are stored as PNG.
When I render the PDF 1 out of 3 times the QR-code looks like this:

[image]

This is how I get the image

```
    function cloud_get($path, $filename)
    {
    $data = [
        'keyFile' => json_decode(file_get_contents("KEYFILE"), true)
    ];
    $storage = new  Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient($data);
    $storage->registerStreamWrapper();
    $content = @file_get_contents('gs://BUCKETNAME/' . $path . $filename);
    if($content === FALSE) {
       return null;
    }
    return $content;


 $qrImg = cloud_get( 'qrcodes/', 'qr-'. UNIQUE_ID . '.png'); ?>
 if(!empty($qrImg)){
     $base64 = 'data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($qrImg);
}
?>
<img src="<?php echo $base64; ?>" width="99" height="99">
```

I tried setting the DPI ($dompdf->set_option( 'dpi' , '72' );)

Saving the image to the server and tried the direct path.

Comment: I'd start by removing that `@` on `@file_get_contents`, so errors don't get ignored.

Comment: The @file_get_contents works fine. But true, I should remove the @.

Comment: If I understand it correctly a [Google bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/buckets) is just a place where you store the PNG file. What does that file look like outside of the PDF? Using a normal image viewer.

Comment: Outside the PDF it's a normal sharp QRcode. Also when I create a copy on the server its a normal sharp QRcode.

Comment: OK, got that, however it's still unclear how you generate the QR PNG files. So at this point the question is: Has this something to do with how you generate the QR images or with DomPDF? You could check if **the same image** sometimes shows normally and sometimes blurry. If that's the case then it is not the image file itself, otherwise it might be due to how you generate the images.

Comment: I've created a workaround. I convert the image to a jpeg and now it's always sharp on the PDF. 
I generate the QRcode with "PHP QR Code encoder" (http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/) with default settings. This images are always sharp when I open them. To test, i've opened a img 25 times, they where al sharp.